# Getting different outputs for C program? What Should this program output?

Tags: c++, c, linux, fork

I am trying to get the output of this program, but it seems to be different depending on the environment I run it.

Is is ABCADEABC or ABCABCADE or ABCADE or EABCDBC or EABCCD?

I believe I should be getting ABCABCADE, but am wondering why I am getting different results when they are the same code?

What should I be getting?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main(void) {
int pid;

    pid= fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "A\n");
        pid= fork();
        if (pid==0) {
            fprintf(stdout, "B\n");
            pid=fork();
            fprintf(stdout, "C\n");
        }
        else {
            wait(NULL);
            fprintf(stdout, "D\n");
        }
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stdout, "E\n");
        wait(NULL);
    }
    // your code goes here
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please post code as text that can be copy/pasted compiled and run. Post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Be clear about the input, the expected output, and the actual output. All we have is an image link and some ABC waffle. State the environments too, in which it works / does not work.

Comment: Post the code in text, not images.  Cut and paste the code in the question and indent it by selecting it and typing Alt-K

Comment: fixed it hopefully

Answer (score 0):

The operating system's scheduler is able to run the processes in any order it wants, so there is no guarantee which order the statements will be executed in. A good scheduling algorithm on a modern operating system will take into account many factors, such as how IO-bound the process is and how much executing time it has used - and preemptive context switches can happen possibly ~60 times a second. We cannot determine exactly how these factors will play out as our processes run with possibly hundreds of others on the system, so there is no correct order for the statements.